# Convert DiscretePlot3D to 2D plot with a Color Function

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, grid-layouts, discrete

Observe the following wolfram Mathematica code:

```
nd[y_, a_, b_, n_] := (Binomial[b - a + 1, y]*Sum[((-1)^i)*Binomial[y, i]*((y - i)/(b - a + 1))^n, {i, 0, y}]);

Animate[DiscretePlot3D[nd[i, 1, n, j], {j, 1, 15}, {i, 1, 15}, ExtentSize -> Full, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"], {n, 1, 50, 1}]
```

nd is just the name of a discrete probability density function of 4 variables that I have defined earlier on.  What I would really like to do is make this a 2 dimensional grid of squares where the value of nd is shown only by the color as opposed to both the color and the height; in other words, I don't want it to be 3D.  Of course, I can rotate what I have to get a top down view, but this isn't exactly ideal:

[image]

I would much prefer to eliminate the third dimension altogether and have a simple grid where the output of nd is shown by a change in color of the squares in the 2D grid.  Is this possible in Mathematica?  If so, how would I do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) will get you what you want, I think. I used `DataReversed -> True` to get the orientation the same as in the 3D plot:

```
Animate[
 ArrayPlot[
  Table[nd[i, 1, n, j], {i, 1, 15}, {j, 1, 15}],
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
  DataReversed -> True,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> Automatic,
  Mesh -> True
  ],
 {n, 1, 50, 1}
 ]
```

[image: ArrayPlot gif]

Comment: Wonderful!  It works beautifully.  Thank you very much!